# Numpy einsum() for rotation of meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have a set of 3d coordinates that was generated using meshgrid(). I want to be able to rotate these about the 3 axes.

I tried unraveling the meshgrid and doing a rotation on each point but the meshgrid is large and I run out of memory.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708840/rotate-meshgrid-with-numpy) addresses this in 2d with einsum(), but I can't figure out the string format when extending it to 3d.

I have read several other pages about einsum() and its format string but haven't been able to figure it out.

**EDIT:**

I call my meshgrid axes X, Y, and Z, each is of shape (213, 48, 37). Also, the actual memory error came when I tried to put the results back into a meshgrid.

When I attempted to 'unravel' it to do point by point rotation I used the following function:

```
def mg2coords(X, Y, Z):
    return np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()]).T
```

I looped over the result with the following:

```
def rotz(angle, point):
    rad = np.radians(angle)
    sin = np.sin(rad)
    cos = np.cos(rad)
    rot = [[cos, -sin, 0],
           [sin,  cos, 0],
           [0, 0, 1]]

    return np.dot(rot, point)
```

After the rotation I will be using the points to interpolate onto.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the mesh and the rotation matrix?  By 'unraveling' do you mean you tried the 2nd answer at your link?  With a little more information I could help with the `einsum`, but I doubt if it is more memory efficient.  Stll we can try.

Comment: @hpaulj, more specifically, I was trying to recreate the meshgrid from the points. Since this set of points was rotated by 15 degrees I bet it made meshgrid go crazy. I am now looking at whether I can use the points themselves to interpolate my 3d data onto.

Comment: I found that I can use the points I rotated using the loop talked about in the original post to interpolate onto, without having to put them into a meshgrid. But I still am quite interested in your ideas on how to do the 3d rotation with einsum(). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with your definitions:

```
In [840]: def mg2coords(X, Y, Z):
        return np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()]).T

In [841]: def rotz(angle):
        rad = np.radians(angle)
        sin = np.sin(rad)
        cos = np.cos(rad)
        rot = [[cos, -sin, 0],
               [sin,  cos, 0],
               [0, 0, 1]]
        return np.array(rot)
        # just to the rotation matrix
```

define a sample grid:

```
In [842]: X,Y,Z=np.meshgrid([0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],indexing='ij')    
In [843]: xyz=mg2coords(X,Y,Z)
```

rotate it row by row:

```
In [844]: xyz1=np.array([np.dot(rot,i) for i in xyz])
```

equivalent `einsum` row by row calculation:

```
In [845]: xyz2=np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',rot,xyz)
```

They match:

```
In [846]: np.allclose(xyz2,xyz1)
Out[846]: True
```

Alternatively I could collect the 3 arrays into one 4d array, and rotate that with `einsum`.  Here `np.array` adds a dimension at the start.  So the `dot` sum `j` dimension is 1st, and the 3d of the arrays follow:

```
In [871]: XYZ=np.array((X,Y,Z))
In [872]: XYZ2=np.einsum('ij,jabc->iabc',rot,XYZ)

In [873]: np.allclose(xyz2[:,0], XYZ2[0,...].ravel())
Out[873]: True
```

Similary for the `1` and `2`.

Alternatively I could split `XYZ2` into 3 component arrays:

```
In [882]: X2,Y2,Z2 = XYZ2
In [883]: np.allclose(X2,xyz2[:,0].reshape(X.shape))
Out[883]: True
```

Use `ji` instead of `ij` if you want to rotate in the other direction, i.e. use `rot.T`.

Comment: I especially appreciate the slight changes you made to the code such as returning the matrix rather than the rotated coords, saves many calculations. Also the list comprehension... I keep forgetting to include these in my code. And thanks for showing the extension to 4d, I may need to used homogeneous coordinates for my transforms.