# 3D rotation of Mgrid

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, rotation

```
import numpy as np
 X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[0:50,0:50,0:50]
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
```

I am trying to rotate this **MGRID** (numpy "not a meshgrid") by some angle around x, y or z axis. What could be the best way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy einsum() for rotation of meshgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816754/numpy-einsum-for-rotation-of-meshgrid)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out.. Yes tried it .. but couldn't do it for mgrid as this is for meshgrid.. if you tried please do share